# How can I do a vlookup with a latest file function in my code

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Hello I using a function that calls out the most recent file in my folder. I need to automate a vlookup for the file. I'm having problems properly calling the file out

I already tried calling it by its path but I believe I didn't call it correctly .

```
Sub oversub()

    'Newest file function

        Dim MyPath As String
        Dim MyFile As String
        Dim LatestFile As String
        Dim LatestDate As Date
        Dim LMD As Date

        MyPath = "C:\Users\TAmon1\Desktop\OverSubscription Dash"
        If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
        MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
        If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
            LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
            If LMD > LatestDate Then
                LatestFile = MyFile
                LatestDate = LMD
            End If
            MyFile = Dir
        Loop
        Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
    Dim wb As Workbook
    'wbstring = MyPath & LatestFile
    Windows("Planning_tool.xlsm").Activate


'Vlookupfunction
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1=VLOOKUP(C[-13],'Router_level_crosstab.csv'!C1:C11,11,FALSE)"
```

Currently I am calling the direct file which does work but when I have the a new file I would need to manually change the file name. I need to incorporate the latest file in the Vlookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim wbCSV As Workbook, wbPlanning as Workbook
Set wbPlanning = Workbooks("Planning_tool.xlsm")
'...
'...
Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile) '<< save the reference to the opened file
'...
'...
'don't rely on activeworkbook, activesheet, etc
wbPlanning.Sheets(1).Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=VLOOKUP(C[-13],'" & wbCSV.Name & "'!C1:C11,11,FALSE)"
```